# How to add a new column based on an aggregate function in pandas

Tags: pandas, group-by

I have a pandas dataframe as follows

```
A, B
----
a, 2
a, 5
a, 6
b, 1
b, 2
```

I'd like to groupby column `A` and sum up the values in column `B` and append it as another column and create the following dataframe

```
A, B, SUM
--------
a, 2, 13
a, 5, 13
a, 6, 13
b, 1, 3
b, 2, 3
```

How can I do that in pandas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `transform`

```
df.assign(SUM=df.groupby('A').B.transform('sum'))
Out[15]: 
   A  B  SUM
0  a  2   13
1  a  5   13
2  a  6   13
3  b  1    3
4  b  2    3
```